# width: calc(auto + 50px); doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there option to make a `#search_inner` as wide as the widest elements inside it + 50px ?
width: calc(auto + 50px); doesn't seem to work. I need the width to be **auto**, not *100%*.

Pure CSS solution would be preferable.

Simplified code sample:

```
<div id="search_outter"> <!-- search window -->
  <div id="search_nav" style="float:left"> <!-- search navbar -->
    ...
  </div>

  <div id="search_inner" style="float:right"> <!-- actual search results -->
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't *think* it's possible, why don't you just use a padding instead? `padding-right:50px`

Comment: Do you want the `search_inner` to take the rest of the space the `search_nav` doesn't use?

Comment: @JacobGray because the result may be or ** Jacob Gray** either **King Jacob Gray the third**, and I need the window to be as wide as the widest search result.

Comment: You can't use `auto` like that.

Comment: @LGSon Yes, take the rest, but only as wide as a _search result_ + 50px.

Comment: Is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/kg20ar66/

Comment: @LGSon Do you know how can I use it, to get a similar result?

Comment: @DeneaNovac Put `overflow: hidden` on your `seach_outter` and it will grow as much as needed to fit the `search_inner`'s size.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, almost, but that's enough. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a full HTML example of your issue, there should be a way (if i have the right idea of your structure), to make any search_inner be same width, else , just set an average  min-width:XXem to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a use of `#search_inner:not(:empty)` selector and add let's say `padding-right:50px;` when your `#search_inner` have some content. so it will be as `wide as content (auto)` + `50px padding` --> example

```
#search_inner:not(:empty){
  padding-right:50px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  width:auto;
}
```

**First snippet-no content**

```css
#search_inner:not(:empty) {
  padding-right: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="search_outter">
  <!-- search window -->
  <div id="search_nav" style="float:left">
    <!-- search navbar -->
    Nav bar
  </div>

  <div id="search_inner" style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

**Second Snippet-some random content**

```css
#search_inner:not(:empty) {
  padding-right: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="search_outter">
  <!-- search window -->
  <div id="search_nav" style="float:left">
    <!-- search navbar -->
    Nav search
  </div>

  <div id="search_inner" style="float:right">Some long random content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate "`auto`" inside the CSS `calc()` expression. However, you could use a pseudo selector to add that space, see demo:

```css
#search_inner {
  background:lightblue;
}

#search_inner:after {
  display:inline-block;
  content:"";
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search_outter">
  <div id="search_nav" style="float:left">
    #search_nav
  </div>

  <div id="search_inner" style="float:right">
    #search_inner
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ne0vkcoh/